# Add decimal month to Date in java

Tags: java, date

i need to add a decimal amount of month to a java date  : 
-> i can use this code with joda time api  to add a natural amount of months to a date. But how can i add a decimal amount of month ( for example 3.5) to a date ?

```
Date date = new Date();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
dateTime = dateTime.plusMonths(3);
Date newDate = dateTime.toDate();
```

Comment: That's easy! You can't.

Comment: You cannot! Try adding half the days of a month instead, if that solves your problem.

Comment: You need to define what's half a month. Is it the same amount of days depending on whether the month is february or march? Or whether it is february of a leap-year or not? Should it add half a day if the amount of days in the month is odd? Or maybe simply considering half a month is 14 days would be enough for your use.

Comment: Assuming with 3.5 months you mean 3 months and 2 weeks (or something similar) why not just `dateTime.plusMonths(3).plusDays(14)` (or 15 days, depending on how you'd define a span of 2 weeks)? Btw, since you are obviously using Joda Time you might want to add the corresponding tag or at least state so in your question.

Comment: There is nothing “natural” about a decimal amount of months.

Comment: Tip: You might consider using [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class and [ISO 8601 durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) instead of clumsy decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an approximation. It’s the best you can get.

```
    long oneMonthInNanos = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.getDuration().toNanos();
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Phnom_Penh"));

    System.out.println("Now           " + now);
    System.out.println("In 3.5 months " + now.plusNanos(Math.round(3.5 * oneMonthInNanos)));
    System.out.println("In 4.5 months " + now.plusNanos(Math.round(4.5 * oneMonthInNanos)));
    System.out.println("In 12 months  " + now.plusNanos(Math.round(12.0 * oneMonthInNanos)));
```

Output when I ran the code just now, was:

> ```
> Now           2018-11-06T22:31:36.460573+07:00[Asia/Phnom_Penh]
> In 3.5 months 2019-02-21T11:13:27.460573+07:00[Asia/Phnom_Penh]
> In 4.5 months 2019-03-23T21:42:33.460573+07:00[Asia/Phnom_Penh]
> In 12 months  2019-11-07T04:20:48.460573+07:00[Asia/Phnom_Penh]
> ```

As has been said in comments, there is no really good definition of a fractional number of months. When you compare the first and the last date-time you also clearly see that 12 months don’t add up to a year precisely, though pretty close. Please check yourself whether the results are good enough for your purpose.

I am using java.time. I din’t know whether something similar is possible in Joda-Time.

Comment: it was a strange and not well calculated demand by the client, actually i offered them another solution which take two integer as number of month and number of days and then calculate exactly the goal date.

Comment: i will check your answer as right because it gave a good approximation to the malformed problem.